# Debugging internet connectivity delay issue

Tags: networking, debug, sniffing, internet-speed

### Problem

For quite some time now, I am experiencing hiccups in my network connection, although the speeds are on par with what ISP offers (tested with https://speed.cloudflare.com/). Specifically, when I go to a website (or even when pinging an IP), there is a *delay* that seems unrelated to *actual speed*.

Here are the speed test results:
[image: test]

Here's the result of pinging wikipedia:

```
$ time ping -c 5 wikipedia.org
PING wikipedia.org (91.198.174.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=46.1 ms
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=48.6 ms
64 bytes from text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org (91.198.174.192): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=48.2 ms
64 bytes from text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org (91.198.174.192): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=46.3 ms

--- wikipedia.org ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 26204ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 46.085/47.527/48.634/1.100 ms

ping -c 5 wikipedia.org  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 27.280 total
                                                         ^--- this is way too high
```

Notice that although the ping response time is on the order of ms (~48ms), the total time taken (as measured by `time`) is way higher (~27s).

I tried to debug this with Wireshark and observed a consistent pattern:
there are `DHCP Discover` packets with a lot of delay in-between, like so:

```
No. Time
13  1.741054670 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 DHCP    590 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xdefe259a
14  4.813077659 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 DHCP    590 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xdefe259a
# ~3s delay
```

Here's a larger context between 2 consecutive ping request/reply:

```
      10 1.115798068 192.168.0.107  91.198.174.192  ICMP 98  Echo (ping) request  id=0x0009, seq=2/512, ttl=64 (reply in 11)
/---> 11 1.163998347 91.198.174.192 192.168.0.107   ICMP 98  Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0009, seq=2/512, ttl=57 (request in 10)
|     12 1.164386243 192.168.0.107  192.168.0.1     DNS  87  Standard query 0x4e78 PTR 192.174.198.91.in-addr.arpa
|     13 1.741054670 0.0.0.0        255.255.255.255 DHCP 590 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xdefe259a
5s    14 4.813077659 0.0.0.0        255.255.255.255 DHCP 590 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xdefe259a
|     15 6.169712508 192.168.0.107  192.168.0.1     DNS  87  Standard query 0x4e78 PTR 192.174.198.91.in-addr.arpa
|     16 6.200238569 192.168.0.1    192.168.0.107   DNS  128 Standard query response 0x4e78 PTR 192.174.198.91.in-addr.arpa PTR text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org
\---> 17 6.200452771 192.168.0.107  91.198.174.192  ICMP 98  Echo (ping) request  id=0x0009, seq=3/768, ttl=64 (reply in 18)
      18 6.246764831 91.198.174.192 192.168.0.107   ICMP 98  Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0009, seq=3/768, ttl=57 (request in 17)
```

I noticed this delay due to `DHCP Discover` in many captures.

---

### What I tried

- static IP (DHCP bypass on router)
- router & computer reset
- different browsers
- different kernels
- wired connection: same delay is experienced on PPPoE
- **different devices**: this problem is not present on any other device connected on this network, so it's very likely it's a Linux / laptop issue

---

### System info

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.0.15-1-MANJARO arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.0
    Desktop: GNOME v: 43.2 Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux

Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82K8 v: Legion S7 15ACH6
    serial: <filter>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: NO DPK serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO
    v: HACN31WW date: 11/19/2021

Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 vendor: Rivet Networks Killer™
    driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
```

---

What can I try to further debug this?

Answer (score 1):

The DHCP Discover messages are probably a red herring, possibly other devices in your network trying to get a dhcp address at the same time you are doing the ping (these are broadcast messages to your network, so everything in the network sees them).

Is the 5s delay consistent between all pings? I would guess the ping is running with an "-i 5" option or something similar, can you check if e.g. you have an alias for ping or something similar?

You can try "ps axuw | grep ping" while your ping is running, and see if the ping command is exactly as you run it, or if it has additional arguments, like the "-i 5" I mentioned above.

**UPDATE**

After looking at your tcpdump in more detail, it seems to be more related to the DNS queries. Notice that there is no answer to the first query at 1.164386243 and after a 5s timeout your resolver retries the query at 6.169712508 to which it receives the reply and the ping can continue normally. You can probably reduce the delay with an option in /etc/resolv.conf, but better if you can debug why your dns server does not respond to the first query.

To verify it is the DNS causing the delay, you can try the ping with -n to avoid the name resolution in the ping (but this same dns 5s delay will be also causing the similar problems in other situations).

Comment: Thanks for this! `ping` is not aliased, so no hidden flags. Some minimal testing indicates that there are no delays with `ping -n`. My `/etc/resolv.conf` only contains `nameserver 192.168.0.1` (the router gateway). I am wondering: if it's really a DNS issue, wouldn't it be noticeable on other devices on the same network as well?

Comment: Added `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` nameservers for now. Will keep a close look on how things evolve.